# Fetch One Attribute of NSManagedObject after Pressing a Button in UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

I'm using core data and I have a tableView to display all user's approvals

I'm using `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch the approvals from core data

I have added these methods which are used when the delegate is notified that the content will change, we tell the tableView to begin updates

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
  }

  func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
  }

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
   // 1
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
      tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    case .Delete:
      tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    default: break
    }
  }

  func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
   // 2 
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
      tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    case .Delete:
      tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    default: break
    }
  }
```

what I understood: the `NSFetchtedResultsController` can monitor changes to the `NSManagedObject` context and update the table to reflect those changes

In `tableViewCell` I have "inquire Again" button which will update the Approval Status

and this is `ApprovalObject` Class:

```
public class ApprovalObject: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged public var reference_no: NSNumber
    @NSManaged public var status: String
    @NSManaged public var date: NSDate
    @NSManaged public var card: Card
    @NSManaged public var hospital: Hospital

}
```

my question is: how to get the value of "status" attribute for specific "ApprovalObject" after pressing the button in the tableViewCell ?? can I just call tableView.beginUpdates() ??

```
@IBAction func inquireApprovalBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
        // what should i do here ???
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to modify your data object, e.g. the `status` of your `ApprovalObject` instance (and save if desired). The `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` should pick up on that and update the cell in question.

Of course, you have at some point deleted the `.Change` case in your switch statement in the delegate callback. Make sure you put it back in. (You can copy it from a "Master-Detail" Xcode template.)

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. So after adding (.Change), no need to add code inside inquireApproval button?

Comment: As stated, you need to modify your data object.